# Do we need both [children] and [young-author] tags to be about young people who write?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed that we have both [children](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/children) and [young-author](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/young-author)

[children](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/children) has the following tag wiki excerpt, my boldface:

> Writing for children to read, or **questions about children who write.**

[young-author](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/young-author) has the following tag wiki excerpt, again my boldface:

> For **questions about issues specifically encountered by young authors.** Don't use this just because you're young; only use this if your question is specific to young authors. If you are asking about the young adult genre, use [young-adult] instead.

Do we really want both? There seems to be considerable overlap between the two, especially given that the boundary between "children" and "young" isn't clear.

Might we want to rename the [children](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/children) tag to, say, [childrens-stories](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/childrens-stories), restrict it to questions about writings for children to read, and fold the other half of the tag into [young-author](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/young-author)?

If we want to keep both as they are, how can we clarify the difference between the two? (When would I use [children](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/children) and when would I use [young-author](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/young-author) on a question?)

How does the community feel?

Comment: Your proposed solution makes sense.

Answer (score 8):

I agree there's a bit of an overlap.

I'd go with your solution:

> ...rename the children tag to, say, childrens-stories, restrict it to questions about writings for children to read, and fold the other half of the tag into young-author?

since it seems the most logical thing to do.

Maybe the sentence "children who write" in [children](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/children)  refers to childrens who are taking writing as an hobby, whereas [young-author](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/young-author)  is targeted against actually published young people. Yet I don't know if its an usual distinction to make. Probably [young-author](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/young-author) could be extended to became a synonim of "young-writer", for that matter.

Comment: +1, but I think "young-author" is directed at non-adults that are writing stories, like adults, they HOPE to publish, not necessarily published authors.

Answer (score 0):

I would not rename "children" as "children-stories", I would take out the "questions about children who write". I might add the obvious, "questions about children [care, behavior, understanding of issues, attitudes, problems, mistakes]", which might be useful for authors that don't have any children of their own but have to write something for a story with modern children (as opposed to their own decades-old memories), and would like to hear from active parents (or grandparents).

Like, "How expert is a modern 9yo on an iPhone? Could they take a surreptitious video of a crime and email it to their father?"

**Conclusion**: after reading comments below, I think we should rename children" to "childrens-stories", keep the "young-author" tag for any under-age aspiring authors, and use the "child-characters" tag for questions about realistic child behavior, attitudes, problems, etc.

Comment: We also have [tag:child-characters]. I think it would apply better to your last question - is it feasible for a child character to do X.

Comment: Adding to what @Galastel said, this seems to teeter on the brink of making the questions not about writing at all. I imagine a lot of those questions would be better fits for [parenting.se], for example (if suitably worded, of course).

Comment: @aCVn As my example question illustrates, this is entirely about writing and fiction. Parenting is about solving real-world problems with children, not fictional problems with fictional children. Galastel is right, there is overlap with child-characters, but the range of things we might wish to ask about fictional children in fictional situations could easily stray off-topic in Parenting. Like "If a kid has been kidnapped, do they know enough to do X?"

Comment: @aCVn But, that said, Parenting might be worth reading/lurking to sample actual parenting and child problems or issues, for the purpose of improving realism in fiction.

Comment: @Amadeus Yes; I'm not saying *categorically* that *all* such questions would by definition be off topic. I can definitely see a lot of that type of questions falling into the "what to write" or "not about writing at all" categories, though. That said, and I have argued this elsewhere also: each question should ideally be judged on *its own* merits. Applies here, too.